# Expected unqualified-id before '.' token in screen display script

Tags: c++, console, codeblocks

I am trying to make a basic console screen using characters that represent positions on a screen. I've got a problem on the lines "char _Screen[screenSize.x][screenSize.y] = MainDisplay.InitializeScreen(screenSize,defaultIcon);" and "display.DisplayScreen(_Screen);"
They are trying to call a function from an instance of the object "display". I am presuming I'm not using the correct syntax, in those lines or when I define the classes. 
I'd really appreciate it if you could tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Vector2 {
   static int x;
   static int y;
};

class Object {
     public:

    static Vector2 Size;
    static Vector2 Position;
    static char icon;
};

class display {
    public:

        void DisplayScreen(char Screen[100][100])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Screen) / sizeof(*Screen);i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(Screen[1]) / sizeof(*Screen[1]);j++)
                {
                    cout << Screen[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        char InitializeScreen(Vector2 Size,char icon)
        {
            char Screen[Size.x][Size.y];
            for (int i = 0; i < Size.y;i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Size.x;j++)
                {
                    Screen[i][j] = icon;
                }
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    Vector2 screenSize;
    screenSize.x = 100;
    screenSize.y = 100;
    char defaultIcon = '.';

    display MainDisplay;
    char _Screen[screenSize.x][screenSize.y] = MainDisplay.InitializeScreen(screenSize,defaultIcon);
    display.DisplayScreen(_Screen);
}
```

Comment: There are lots of misunderstanding in this code. You really need to go back to your books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to try and cover some of the significant misunderstandings you have about C++. The code above isn't fixable, you need to start again. In particular you need to learn how to use vectors instead of arrays. Arrays have all sorts of quirks in C++ that make them difficult to use, vectors are easier.

1) You can't declare arrays unless the size of the array is a *compile time constant*. So this is not legal

```
char Screen[Size.x][Size.y];
```

because `Size.x` and `Size.y` are variables. This would be OK

```
char Screen[100][100];
```

If you need a variable sized array the technique is to use *dynamic allocation*. The simple way to do dynamic allocation is to use the `std::vector` class. Here's a 2D vector of `char` in C++

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> Screen(Size.x, std::vector<char>(Size.y));
```

2) You can't return an array from a function, so even ignoring point 1, this is not legal

```
char _Screen[screenSize.x][screenSize.y] = MainDisplay.InitializeScreen(screenSize,defaultIcon);
```

Again the usual answer to the problems with arrays is to use `std::vector` which can be returned from a function.

3) You cannot pass an array to a function in C++. So although this code is legal

```
    void DisplayScreen(char Screen[100][100])
```

`Screen` in not an array in this code, it is a pointer. Any attempt to declare an array as a parameter of a function in C++ is converted to a pointer instead. This is especially confusing to beginners. The answer to this problem is to use `std::vector` instead of arrays. Vectors can be passed as parameters to functions.

4) You cannot use `sizeof` to get the size of the array that a pointer is pointing at. So this code is legal but doesn't work as you are expecting

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Screen) / sizeof(*Screen);i++)
```

This code would work if `Screen` was an array but as explained in point 3 it isn't, it's a pointer. The answer to this problem is to use `std::vector` instead of arrays as vectors have a built in `size` method which returns the vectors size, like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.size(); i++)
```

5) Finally you have declared your screen in two different places, in `main` and in `InitializeScreen`. These are different screens, which presumably is not what you intended. Looking at your code I would guess that the correct place to declare your screen is actually in the display class, since it seems you want both methods of the `display` class to reference the same screen. Class design is another aspect of programming that beginners struggle with.

In short, go back to your book, and read the chapter on vectors, or at the very least read a proper tutorial on arrays and pointers that explains the many limitations of using arrays.